# How to get 64-bit "program files" directory in 32-bit Application

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I have an application compiled in x86 mode (in c#) from which I need to access a certain file that exists in the 64-bit program files folder (of a 64-bit Windows of course).
I don't want to just hardcode `C:\Program Files` as a string in my application because a few target computers may have Windows installed in a different drive, or may be in another languages.

The problem I'm encountering is that using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)` returns the x86 flavor instead of the desired directory, unless I compile my program in 64-bit mode. Out of curiosity, what can I do to avoid doing such?

Comment: change your project's Build Properties to be Build -`Platform target = AnyCpu` if you are not familiar then `Right click on the project, then select properties, from there click the Build node on the Left and change x86 to AnyCPU`

Comment: @MethodMan That's the choosen option already in my project. Any other suggestion?

Comment: what's the chosen option change it.. as I have just suggested.. and I tried your code and `AnyCPU and x64` both return `C:\ Program Files` vs `C:\Program Files(x86)`

Comment: @MethodMan hah. There was an option called "prefer 32-bit" in the project properties. Unchecking that option did the trick. I'm still interested in a code solution instead of this, nevertheless.

Comment: how about `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramW6432")`

Comment: Is this your own program or a program someone else wrote?  Normally when I write both a 32bit and 64bit application I store any shared files between them in the `CommonApplicationData`.

Comment: Here's a full list of [Environment Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 7):

> There was an option called "prefer 32-bit" in the project properties. Unchecking that option did the trick. I'm still interested in a code solution instead of this, nevertheless.

I actually think disabling *Prefer 32bit* on the build options is the better way to go. If you don't want your program to be treated like a 32 bit process, why not make it a 64 bit process and save yourself some trouble.

See also [this article on the subject by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/22/9244582.aspx).

Having said that, the `ProgramW6432` environment variable suggested by griddoor worked fine for me when I tried it.

Comment: Notice they said " unless I compile my program in 64-bit mode"?  Meaning they know they can switch it to being a 64 bit application, and I think it is safe to assume they don't want to or can't do that.  You don't just switch your 32 bit application to a 64 bit application so you can more easily find the 64 bit Program Files directory.  This should be a deliberate change, should not be taken lightly, and should never be done for such silly reasons.  There are very real reasons to stay 32 bit such as needed to utilize 32 bit native libraries.

Comment: @GregCobb Yes, and I also noticed (several years ago, when this was written) that after someone in the comments suggested unchecking `Prefer 32 bit`, OP wrote "that did the trick", but was still interested in a code solution. That being the case, I stated in my answer that the `ProgramW6432` environment variable seemed to work for me and so OP should perhaps try it. Given the upvotes on the comment that made that suggestion, I take it that it worked for other people as well.

Comment: @GregCobb that said, I think it's perfectly valid for me to advocate unchecking `Prefer 32 bit` when possible, and I laid out the reasoning for that by linking to the Raymond Chen post. Should it be used in all situations? No, and I never stated otherwise. I feel like the caveat, "**if** you don't want your program to be treated like a 32 bit process" should be enough for most people, including both the OP and yourself. Nevertheless, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @GregCobb indeed that was exactly my scenario, the project could not be ported to 64-bits because of a native 32-bit library with no alternative available at the time. Thank you both Greg and Nacimota for your considerations, they are all very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that the WinAPI does not support what you require.
Due to virtualization it is not possible for a 32bit application to get the path to 64bit directories.

Refer to: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/37e798f5-1b9b-42ce-89af-486ee3531c0b/32-bit-app-how-to-get-cprogram-files-directory-using-environmentgetfolderpath?forum=csharpgeneral

Any attempt to "guess" the right path or use the registry could cause an issue in the future...

Comment: Fortunately, "In the future", most software should get patched anyway, or not be 32-bit any more, so just hard-coding the path would be good enough for most practical purposes. Greeting from the future!

Answer (score 2):

In Build Settings, uncheck the option `Prefer 32-bit`. 
Now `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86` will return a 32-bit path and `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` will return a 64-bit path.

Comment: That's it! This answer should have a lot more upvotes!

Comment: No, this does not work from a 32-bit application. Both return the (X86) folder.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can be reasonably assured:

1. Program Files directories exist on the same drive as the system is installed.
2. They are named Program Files for x64 and x86, and Program Files (x86) for x64.

Then you could do something like this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string baseDirectory = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
        string programFiles = "Program Files";
        string programFilesX86 = "Program Files (x86)";

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "64-Bit Process" : "32-Bit Process");

        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("64-bit operating system");
            Console.WriteLine("Program Files Directory: " + Path.Combine(baseDirectory, programFiles));
            Console.WriteLine("Program Files x86 Directory: " + Path.Combine(baseDirectory, programFilesX86));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("32-bit operating system");
            Console.WriteLine("Program Files Directory: " + Path.Combine(baseDirectory, programFiles));
        }
        
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

However, there is one thing to note:

The program files directories *can* be changed, although it is not supported by Microsoft and may result in other system issues.

So I would follow those up with a good `Directory.Exists` and if you don't find them, then you can look in the registry. The keys you are looking for are:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
>
> - ProgramFilesDir
> - ProgramFilesDir(x86)

But again, with registry access are some caveats that are hard to get, when using the `Registry` class, it will pick the 64-bit or 32-bit registry based on the processor architecture of the process requesting it. You can specify the 64-bit directory. Don't want to get too into it, there are a lot of tutorials out there on how to read the registry.

Also note that this only works with Windows Vista and up, I don't remember how the strange Windows XP-64 handled it, or older versions of Windows Server.

And the last note, Linux/Android/iOS (aka, Mono compatible OS's or Micro Framework) do not have a "Program Files" directory, so make sure you realize you are writing OS specific code here. If you want to make it a little more OS agnostic, consider writing a function that can return an array of strings based on the current OS for default installation directories.

Comment: The "Program Files" directory is not called "Program Files" when you are running a non-English version of Windows.  That is why you can't use hard coded strings.